Ajax/JavaScript get request to update a HTML element
I am trying to make an empty circle appear when the contents of a GET request are a 0, and a full circle appear when the contents are 1. I am not really sure how to implement this. Needs to poll every 5 seconds or so.
<style>
    .emptycircle {
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 20px;
          width: 20px;
          border: 2px solid red;
        }
       .fullcircle {
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 20px;
          width: 20px;
          border: 2px solid red;
          background-color: #f00;
        }       
...
<p id="state" class="emptycircle"></p>
...
<script>
    function getState() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/state',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
      if (getState == 0) {
        var state = '.emptycircle';
      } else {
        state = '.fullcircle';
      }
    }
</script>

Currently, invoking getState() from the console returns 'undefined 0' or 'undefined 1' (with undefined and the number being each on their own line), which is sort of the correct behaviour, so I just need to connect that to the element with id "state" and then have the script run every few seconds.

Do what you need to do that relies on data in the success callback where you’re doing your log. Trying to access it outside of that won’t work as data hasn’t been set yet.

There were several things wrong with your attempt. Here is a working version that demonstrates how it could be done instead.
The following demo uses a public REST API with a random result: https://dummyjson.com/todos/random. I use the completed property of the result to determine whether I want the full or the empty circle appering.
In order to do so I defined the function setState(full) with a boolean argument full. Depending on this argument the function will assign the class fullcircle to the paragraph #state if it was true and emptycircle if it was false.
I also introduced the setInterval() function to get a fresh result every 5 seconds.


function getState() {
  $.ajax({
    // url: '/state',
    url: 'https://dummyjson.com/todos/random',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.id,data.completed);
      setState(data.completed);
    }
  });
}

function setState(full) {
  $("#state")[0].className=full?'fullcircle':'emptycircle';
}

setInterval(getState, 5000);
.emptycircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.fullcircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #f00;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="state" class="emptycircle"></p>



Or, even shorter - and without jQuery:


const p=document.getElementById("state");
setInterval(()=>{
 fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos/random').then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>{
  console.log(d.id,d.completed);
  p.className=d.completed?'fullcircle':'emptycircle';
 })}, 5000);
.emptycircle, .fullcircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.fullcircle { background-color: #f00; }
}
<p id="state" class="emptycircle"></p>




Thanks! this plus some basic if else logic was exactly what I needed. glad i don't have to mess around with websockets
